# TypeError: i.s is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript

Keep getting these errors, any help to make this work whould be greatly appreciated

```
"undefined" == typeof sjsHack && (window.sjsHack = {}),
   function(s) {
     var i = window;
     this.getToken = function() {
       return i.s(this.email, this.score, i.token);
     }, this.hack = function(s, i) {
       this.score = i, this.email = s, $.ajax({
         url: "http://www.slamjamsocialism.com/arcad-ism/arcad-ism.php",
         data: "action=setpoint&email=" + s + "&pointz=" + i + "&sec=" + this.getToken(),
         type: "POST"
       });
     };
   }.call(sjsHack);
 sjsHack.hack("pp10@gmail.com", 199);
```

Comment: are you sure **s** is a function

Comment: What you expect `window.s` to be? It's definitely not a native property. Notice also, that the passed `s` is `undefined` (`sjsHack` is the `this` value to be used in the function).

Comment: honestly not sure was given this to run and does not work

Comment: Hmm... there's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39619319/1169519) with the same code, a question at Reddit with a [Github link](https://github.com/RobertChristopher/sjs-game-hack/commit/b874cbc816c71ddcbee48d2f48a55701530de77f). All yours?

Comment: Post the full code also note that posts related to **illegal** hacking aren't allowed here